# how to make a scene with characters linked to renderfarm?

Tags: rendering

I have a scene with characters linked with animation and everything else, but ... I will render to render farm with networkrender, but in the result, no frames where my characters do not appear, guess where these frames are not rendered my characters correspond to the slaves which is not native scene, which I do? sorry for the translation, I speak Spanish. Thank you!

Comment: Es possible editar la pregunta para incluir el texto en español? Sin ofender, pero el ingles de la pregunta es mas o menos incomprensible... :(